# Hyper-V: after external switch setup - host lose internet in browser (but I still connected to it)

Tags: windows, networking, hyper-v

I have a dedicated server with Windows 10 - far away from me, in datacenter.

I create external switch in Hyper-V to connect my VMs to Internet with "white" IPs.
I attach it to NIC with internet (server also have other NIC, but it not connected, maybe for datacenter local network, I think).

When I apply this external switch, my host lost internet in browser (!), but I still have connection by RDP without any problem (!). Somehow I see my server in Internet, but my server not see Internet.

---

On previous server I have connection with external switch without any problems. What can be cause of problem? Maybe it something with new 'Default Switch' in Hyper-V, that cannot be deleted?

Comment: windows 10 as hyper-v host in an Produktion Environment? i think your on a wrong site, try superuser. com

Comment: @djdomi but why not, in fact? It wonderful fits for SOHO

Comment: Because it's not a supported platform.

Comment: `I have a dedicated server with Windows 10` - Windows 10 is not a server operating system.

Comment: if you dont have the money for hosting it correctly then yozr bancrupacy will be soon

Comment: @djdomi oh god please mister, you even can't write "bankruptcy" correct. I just ask a techical question about strange behavior of Hyper-V, I don't need business audit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I find solution (and not, problem was here not because 'aah, windows 10 is not server OS'):

When Hyper-V create external switch, it removes DNS-servers from main connection settings. After switch delete - it restores it back.

So I write it manually to main connection - and everything works fine.

Comment: There is discussion here on workaround.    https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/365a0fb2-332e-43b8-9913-0191d0b32bb8/hyperv-on-host-virtual-switches-leads-to-very-slow-or-no-internet-on-host-at-all?forum=MVMC